# How to get only the first n layers of a network loaded from a .pb file

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

**What I want:** A protobuf file which contains all the layers of a pretrained AlexNet up until the pool5 layer.

**What I have:** I downloaded the file of the weights of AlexNet [here](https://zenodo.org/record/1208034) and 
converted it to a protobuf file of the model and a frozen protobuf file with [this](https://github.com/huanzhang12/tensorflow-alexnet-model) code.
I loaded the resulting protobuf file with this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile
from tensorflow.contrib import graph_editor as editor

GRAPH_PB_PATH = 'alexnet.pb'
with tf.Session() as sess:
   print("load graph")
   with gfile.FastGFile(GRAPH_PB_PATH,'rb') as f:
       graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
   graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
   sess.graph.as_default()
   tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
   writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('logs', sess.graph)
   writer.close()
   graph_nodes=[n for n in graph_def.node]
   names = []
   for t in graph_nodes:
      names.append(t.name)
   print(names)
```

Now I want to throw away all layers subsequent to the `pool5` layer, such that the input of the network is an image and the output is whatever `pool5` return (i.e. some vector). I would like to save the resulting, and now way smaller network into a protobuf file again.
So how do I delete the unnecessary layers?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
with open('alexnet.pb', 'rb') as f:
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
    importer.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

new_model = tf.GraphDef()

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:    
    for n in sess.graph_def.node:            
        nn = new_model.node.add()
        nn.CopyFrom(n)
        if n.op.name == 'pool5':
            break;

tf.train.write_graph(new_model, '.', 'cut_model.pb', as_text=False)
```